# Multidimensional array initialization seems sensitive to whitespace

Tags: powershell, declaration

I noticed a difference between those two declarations where only the position of the comma changes:

```
$a = @( @('a','b'),
        @('c','d'))

$b = @( @('a','b')
      , @('c','d'))
```

In this case, `$a.length` evaluates to 2 and `$b.length` evaluates to 3. The first sub-array of `$b` has been flattened.

Is this a feature and where can I find its documentation?

By the way, `$PSVersionTable`:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 , Comma operator
         As a binary operator, the comma creates an array. As a unary
         operator, the comma creates an array with one member. Place the
         comma before the member.
```

[Source.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx)

Its because `@('a','b')` will push two strings `a` and `b` into the array `$b` whereas you force `@('c','d')`to get pushed into `$b` as an `array` using a comma.

Example:

```
$b = @( @('a','b')
      , @('c','d'))

$b | foreach { Write-Host "Item: $_"}
```

Output:

```
Item: a
Item: b
Item: c d
```

And if you look at the types:

```
$b | foreach { $_.GetType()}
```

You get:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType     
-------- -------- ----     --------     
True     True     String   System.Object
True     True     String   System.Object
True     True     Object[] System.Array
```

---

To force `$b` to contain two `arrays`, use the comma binary operator:

```
$b = @(@('a','b'),@('c','d'))
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your answer. `$b = @(@('a','b'),@('c','d'))` contains two arrays without comma. What is the difference when I insert newline BEFORE the comma and AFTER the comma?

Comment: You are right. Its because in this case the `comma` is used as a binary operator, see my edit.

Comment: Does that mean binary operators cannot follow newline?

Comment: Yes it does. You can validate that if you adding a backtick ` to the end of the first line, then the comma is treated as a binary operator