# how to put multiple value into one variabel in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I tried to move some files with a certain extension to another folder using powershell, but I can't put multiple values to the variable "$Ext", this is the code I made. can someone help fix my code?

```
$Date = Get-Date -UFormat %d-%m-%Y
$Source = 'C:\Source\'
$Temp = 'C:\Backup-Temp\'
$Nas = 'D:\Destination\'
$Ext = '*.zip,*.rar, *.txt '
$SetTime = '-5'

New-Item -Path $Temp -Name Backup-$Date -ItemType "directory"
get-childitem -Path $Source/$Ext -Recurse  |
  Where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays($SetTime)} | 
    Move-item -destination $Temp\Backup-$Date
Compress-Archive -Path $Temp\Backup-$Date  -DestinationPath $Nas\Backup-$date.Zip
```

Comment: Look at arrays.

$ext = '*.zip', '*.rar', '*.txt'

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758514/how-to-declare-an-array-of-strings-on-multiple-lines/37758722#37758722

Comment: Update-Help (from elevated prompt)

get-help about_Arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but something like this should work.

We are first finding each file recursively with a certain extension, one by one. Then we proceed to move it and compress it.

```
$Date = Get-Date -UFormat %d-%m-%Y
$Source = 'C:\Source\'
$Temp = 'C:\Backup-Temp\'
$Nas = 'D:\Destination\'
$Ext = "*.zip","*.rar","*.txt"
$SetTime = '-5'

New-Item -Path $Temp -Name "Backup-$Date" -ItemType "directory"

Foreach ($Extension in $Ext) {
get-childitem -Path "$Source" -Recurse |  Where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays($SetTime) -and $_.name -like "$Ext"} | Move-item -destination "$Temp\Backup-$Date" | Compress-Archive -Path "$Temp\Backup-$Date"  -DestinationPath "$Nas\Backup-$date.Zip"
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, and it is the way I want, thank you for the help.

Comment: It can probably be optimized by specifying the extension in get-childitem so where-object has less to parse.  - just add "*.$Extension" to the get-childitem side, and remove the `-and $_.name -like "$ext"`  - also i just realized he identifies each individual extension but then loops through with $ext in the where filter.